# Remove duplicate records from dataset in c#

Tags: c#, excel

I need to upload data from excel sheet to my grid view. but I need to prevent insertion of duplicate rows. so how can I do this with my dataset ? how do I check the dataset if it contains duplicates. if it has duplicates, I need to give an error message. here is my code.

```
odfExcelGet.Title = "Excel Upload";

odfExcelGet.FileName = "Excel";
odfExcelGet.Filter = "Excel File (*.xls;*.xlsx;)|*.xls;*.xlsx;";
odfExcelGet.InitialDirectory = @"c:\";
odfExcelGet.ShowDialog();
txtAddress.Text = odfExcelGet.FileName;

this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor; 

string ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=";
ConnectionString += odfExcelGet.FileName;
ConnectionString += @";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";";

OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", ConnectionString);
da.Fill(dsMain);

dgGrid.DataSource = dsMain.Tables[0];
```

how do I modify this code to prevent duplication.

Comment: I referred above link. but is there any other way to do this? I mean without using hash table?

Comment: Instead of `select * from [Sheet1$]`, try `select distinct * from [Sheet1$]` - that might work. But it depends on your definition of unique

Comment: thanks Nick. but the requirement of mine is differ from this solution.

Comment: @Didu Please check my answer below and let me know whether it is working or not. If yes please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

A Simple way would be,
Replace ColumnType with Type of your column which is unique.

```
var newDataTable = dsMain.Tables[0];
dgGrid.DataSource = newDataTable.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(col => col.Field<ColumnType>("ColumnName"))
.Select(x=>x.First()).CopyToDataTable();
```